# HTML5, SQLite transaction question

Tags: javascript, sqlite, transactions, cordova

In my HTML5, i have a for loop which calls a function to insert into a database. I need this function to be inside a single transaction.

```
function Ins(id){
db.transaction(function(tx){
tx.executeSql('insert into Product(id) values(?);', [iName], function() {}, function() { });
}); 
}
```

The for loop

```
    db.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql("BEGIN",[]);});
    for (intCountLine=1;intCountLine<=1000;intCountLine++)
    {
    Ins(intCount);
    }
   db.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql("COMMIT",[]);});
```

You can see, i have the transaction begin & commit, but i assume when it calls the INS function, it would open a new transaction and close it, everytime it is called. How do i make sure that doesn't happen.

googled it but could not find it... throw me some light here....

Answer (score 1):

May be this will works. Use `insert select union all` instead of creating 1000 insert statements. But this can insert only 500 rows at a time. Here is the code which i worked on, do a test on Google chrome i am sure it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var msg;
var j=1;
var i=1;
var quer="";
db.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, todo TEXT)",[]);});
db.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql("delete from logs",[]);});
txquer();
showMsg();
function txquer()
{
  quer="insert into logs ";
 for(i=j;i<=j+498;i++)
 {
  quer+=" select "+i+",'test' union all";
  }
  quer+=" select "+i+",'test' ; ";
  j=i+1;
    db.transaction(
    function(tx){
      tx.executeSql(quer,[]);    
    }
    );

}

function showMsg(){
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT count(*) todo FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
   var len = results.rows.item(0).todo;
   msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
   document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;  
 }, null);
});
```

}